# Div background scalling for Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, image-scaling

I'm just beginning my adventure with Bootstrap and I've got a responsive design to code. This is a project which I've bought and now I need to make it clickable :) 
It's done based on `bootstrap` grid and has a `1920px width`.

**My question is:** how to make this element `background` (background image and white frame sepparately or together in one layer - don't know which be better) responsive to fit `retina` and all `others devices`. I was trying with different `image resolutions` (from `1920px to 1200px`) and with many css commands but it always looks different at least on retina. I know it's probably connected to large screen different columns widths, but have no idea how to handle it.

I will apprectiate all kinds of help.

Here you can see design element: [image: here]

Comment: write in code, what you just tried ?

Comment: I've tried with:

background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;

and also with:

background-size: 100% 100%;

and many more. I suppose my problem is including wrong image into background, but have no idea how to prepare it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Media queries. Place different background for different screen sizes.